# Highcharts drilldown error: Cannot read property 'getBBox' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to use the Highcharts async drilldown module shown in the demo on http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/async/.

The demo uses a column chart with categories. I'm trying to reproduce this using line charts.

I mocked up a simple prototype which drills down from one series to another using highstock sample data. The data for both the initial series and the drilldown is loaded by ajax.

When I click on a series point, I get an error on `chart.addSeriesAsDrilldown`: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBBox' of undefined`

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/adamtsiopani/bt9gnakj/15/

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

## Update

Highslide-software committed two patches for this error in the past 24 hours: `dc0cbf2` and `69f8312` on `master`. The patches have yet to be released yet, however if you use the master version of the code as of 2015-01-13 then the BBox bug will be fixed.

Comment: I think this is related to my bug here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3197. Your drilldown series does not yet exist so highcharts is not sure where to place it.

Comment: @wergeld what do you mean it "does not yet exist"? Isn't the whole point of drilldown.js supposed to asynchronously pull the data and then add it to the chart's set of series?

Comment: It means that chart is faster redrawn than series is loaded. It is buggy as wergeld said, so you need to waint until fix will be published, or destroy chart and create new one.

Comment: @Adam, latest commit on that issue solves my BBox error. See: http://jsfiddle.net/x3u2bg8y/. Does yours work now?

Comment: @wergeld commit `dc0cbf2` solves my BBox error.